# Is it possible to insert a slicer in an Excel 2010 pivot table that is connected to a SQL server database via an ODBC connection?

Tags: excel, odbc, excel-2010, pivot-table

The data source is connected via a connection string and command text as follows:

```
With objPivotCache
    .connection = "DRIVER=SQL Server;Integrated Security=SSPI;SERVER=Server035;WSID=;DATABASE=db_Warehouse"
    .CommandText = strSomeCommandString
End With
```

The reason I ask is because when I try to insert slicers in the Options tab of the pivot table, the "Insert Slicer" option is grayed out.

Comment: Apparently it is "This tutorial covers a straight forward scenario with an Excel 2010 PivotTable connected to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database using a simple SQL query. I am also using Slicers for visual filtering which is new in Excel 2010." -- http://newtech.about.com/od/tutorials/ss/How-To-Configure-Excel-2010-Pivot-Table-For-Business-Intelligence.htm

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, I created a pivot table manually with SQL Server Express on an ODBC connection and I found that the slicer was available. On checking, the Connection was `ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server; <..>`

Comment: Hmm... any other ideas of why it may be grayed out? I've read that it sometimes happens when you are in compatibility mode due to the workbook being created in an earlier version of Excel, but this is not the case with my file. I am able to create a pivot table based on data in a sheet in the workbook, and can then add slicers.

Comment: Not really, but here are a couple of thoughts. If you are using Excel 2010, why do you need to use ODBC? There is an option when setting up manually to get data from SQL Server, which creates an OLEDB connection. Have you tried creating the oivot table manually?

Comment: It is connecting to a stored procedure. When setting up a manual connection I can only see the tables in the database, not stored procedures, so I can't create the OLEDB connection